# R rename excel sheet using variable

Tags: r

I am using `write.xlsx` and trying to rename  an excel sheet to include the current date like bellow:

```
write.xlsx(dt, file = "C:\\Users\\Docs\\sheet",format(Sys.Date(),"%d_%m_%y"),".xlsx",row.names=FALSE,sheetName = "DATA")
```

I get the error

```
Error in if (col.names) iOffset <- 1 : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

I need the file to be sheet20_09_2021.xlsx. It works using write.csv2 but not using write.xlsx

What is the correct approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forgot to paste your filename first.

```r
ofile <- paste0("C:\\Users\\Docs\\sheet",format(Sys.Date(),"%d_%m_%y"),".xlsx")

ofile
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\Docs\\sheet20_09_21.xlsx"

write.xlsx(dt, file = ofile,row.names=FALSE,sheetName = "DATA")
```

Comment: Thats correct !! Thank you.